# "Not" or "no" in "yet every mother breeds not sons alike"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In the following sentence from the Merriam Webster's entry for *breed*:

> yet every mother breeds not sons alike (Shakespeare)

I'm wondering the usage of "not" is grammatically correct. Normally I would use "no" instead of "not" in such situation. So is that a play on words or is it actually correct usage of "not"?

Comment: Where did you find this expression? It looks like something from an older literary work (_breeds not = does not breed_), not something we would say in modern English.

Comment: It's from Shakespeare's *Titus Andronicus*.

Comment: But I actually found it on Webster.

Comment: You should have supplied that information in your question, and/or given a link 
 (I assume you mean the Merriam-Webster dictionary?).  It seems to mean "Not every mother brings up sons who are all alike".

Comment: @KateBunting, you're right about the dictionary. I've added the info.

Comment: "yet every mother breeds no sons alike" wouldn't mean the same thing (the difference between "not all" and "none".) This use of "not" after a verb for a negation is archaic (in standard English, in most contexts). But this doesn't seem like a question for language learners, as it's about early modern English literature.

Comment: @StuartF - Yes, but the quotation is given as an example in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/breed).

Comment: It wasn't written in current modern English. Shakespeare wrote in early modern English (EModE), around 430 years ago, at a time when grammar rules were a little different from now.  In current modern English it would be "Yet every mother does not breed sons [who are] alike".  Some other examples of similar construction: "Think not I love him, though I ask for him;" becomes "Do not think [that] I love him, though I ask for him", and "He that loveth me not keepeth not my sayings" becomes "He that does not love me does not keep my sayings".

Comment: Out of context, I take it to mean “not all mothers have similar sons” or “not all mothers raise sons in the same way”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, I never question Shakespeare but I do make sure it is from him.

**yet every mother breeds not sons alike (Shakespeare)
can be stated in modern English like this:

yet every mother does not breed sons who are like each other